# Why doesn't Popup Kendo close when I click on Update?

Tags: popup, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When Popup window opens and I click on update, the window doesn't close

I want the window close when I click on Update

[**jsfiddle code**](http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/hRJfv/32/embedded/result/)

**Button update code**

```
save: function (e) {

            $.ajax({

                url: '/api/apdevice',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(e.model),

                success: function (data) {
                  alert('yes');

                },

                error: function (data) {
                   alert('no');
                }

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the grid what to do after a success or error. Check out the [grid methods](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods). In this example I used [refresh](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-refresh) and [cancelRow](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-cancelRow).

```
save: function (e) {
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({

        url: '/api/apdevice',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(e.model),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('yes');
            that.refresh();
        },

        error: function (data) {
            alert('no');
            that.cancelRow();
        }

    });
}
```

Here's some updated fiddles:

- [Simulated save with ajax error](http://jsfiddle.net/hRJfv/41/)
- [Simulated save with ajax success](http://jsfiddle.net/hRJfv/42/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem was solved. But there is an error after update
firefox browser,
TypeError: r is undefined,
Chrome browser
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined,

Also includes a video put me in this regard so I can understand better.http://youtu.be/Ae5u7mFw79A